# ServiceStack 5.1.0 does not deserialize object field

Tags: servicestack

We have Web Client (Javascript) sending DTO containing field of type object and having some string inside. Server handles the string (there is some reason why the field is defined as 'object' and not 'string', let's take it as given for this discussion).

This worked fine with ServiceStack 4.0.52 but stopped working with ServiceStack 5.1.0 (.NET Standard). The field arrives to service side as null and the string cannot be processed.

Any reason why this happens? If it a bug or intended change breaking compatibility? If latter case is there any option to return old behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unknown `object` Types should be avoided, other than interoperability issues of not being supported in other languages and serializers, it's also subject to [security restrictions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#late-bound-object-and-interface-runtime-types).

In v5.1.0 it was changed to [accept arbitrary JS objects](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.1.0#accept-arbitrary-javascript-or-json-objects) using the new [JS Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) implementation which is more capable and correct then the previous implementation.

But the previous implementation can be restored with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { UseJsObject = false });
```

Comment: This works, thanks.

Is there any "breaking changes" document explaining such kind of incompatibilities in ServiceStack versions?